# Copy and Paste Specific Rows from Multiples tabs into Another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So what I'm trying to do is consolidate all of the rows in multiple tabs of one workbook (wrksource) and paste them into one tab in another workbook (wrk). Basically on a daily basis I get a file with multiple tabs, I want the code to intereate through all the tabs, identify all the rows that have "USD" in column "G", copy all of those rows and paste all of it in the tab named "USD Historic" in the other workbook. So far I've come up with the following code, however I keep getting a "Type Mismatch" error. Appreciate any advice or input. Thanks!

Update: I've changed the code to the following, the file opens the source excel document however an error message "Subscript out of range" is popping up. Any advice is apprciated. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
   Sub combine()

   Dim wbk As Workbook
   Dim wbksource As Workbook
   Dim s As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Lastrow As Long

   'Define Workbook with VBA
   Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

   'Define Source workbook
   Set wbksource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kgomes\Desktop\New folder\Daily Currency Values\USD Today.xls")

   For s = 1 To wbksource.Worksheets.Count

   Application.GoTo Sheets(s).[a1]

   Lastrow = Sheets(s).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

           If wrksource.Sheets(s).Cells(i, "G").Value = wbk.Sheets("USD Historic").Range("U1") Then

           wrksource.Sheets(s).Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Select
           Selection.Copy Destination:=wbk.Sheets("USD Historic").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

           End If
        Next
   Next

   End Sub
```

Comment: What line of code is giving the error message?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code.

The first is that you have tried to declare the variables at the same time.  This doesn't work.  As written, wbk is declared as a variant (as you didn't give it a type) and wbksource is declared as an object of type "Workbooks," which is not what you are trying to do.  Replace that line with:

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wbksource As Workbook
```

Second, the loop through the worksheets won't work as written.  Update it to:

```
For Each s In wbksource.Worksheets
```

Then it will loop through the worksheets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. I made the above updates and am still getting an error message. More specifically on the loop change. I'm now getting an error message indicating "Method or data member not found". Any ideas on how to get past this?

Comment: Is there a file in the location?  check to see what the worksheet "wbksource" is equal to before this line.

Comment: Yea, the file is in the location as indicated in the path. Usually the code opens the file while it runs though and for some reason it isn't opening anymore.

Comment: So got the file to open, it was a typo on my part, i defined wbksource as "Workbooks" as oppose to just "Workbook". Now the file opens however I'm getting another error message: "Subscript out of range"

Comment: Please provide where the error message is occuring.

Comment: I updated the code in my initial question to reflect what I'm looking at now. The "subscript out of range" error occurs in line 13: 
'Lastrow = wbksource.Sheets(s.Name).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row'

Comment: Try changing this to 'Lastrow = s.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row'

Comment: Didn't work got the same error. I tried changing the 's' variable type from a worksheet to a long. The code runs through that line now but at line 16 we get an "Object Required" error.
'wrksource.Sheets(s).Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Select'
Might have something to do with the code not properly picking up the "USD" appropriate rows, and hence not knowing what to select and copy. Any thoughts? Really appreciate all your help thus far.

Comment: You've changed it from "wbkSource" to "wrkSource" in the middle of your code.  Put "Option Explicit" at the top of your module to ensure these types of misspellings don't happen.

Comment: Thanks! I made some minor changes to the copy and paste functions in the if statement as well and it seem to be working! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I did a few tiny changes and it worked fine here, try this out:

```
Sub combine()

Dim wbk             As Workbooks
Dim wbksource       As Workbooks
Dim lstr            As Long
Dim lstr2           As Long

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\kgomes\Desktop\New folder\Daily Currency Values\USD Today.xls")

Set wbksource = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 1 To wbksource.Worksheets.Count

lstr = Sheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lstr
    If Sheets(i).Cells(i, "G") = "USD" Then

        lstr2 = Sheets("USD Historic").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets(i).Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Copy
        wbk.Worksheets("USD Historic").Range("A" & lstr2).Paste

    End If
    Next

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think were getting close, tested your code and for some reason I'm getting the error message: "Methods or data member not found" on the For loop statement in line 9. Any advise on how to get through that? Appreciate all the help!

        For i = 1 To wbksource.Worksheets.Count

Comment: Really weird, i tried some test here and couldn't finde out why, sorry =/ i'll look further on that.

Comment: So it was a typo, in the definition "Workbooks" should have read "Workbook". Now that's fixed however I'm getting another error for line 11 indicating "For control variable already in use".

Comment: You are using two loop with (one nested) with the name "i".

Comment: Good to see that you've located the errors @Kaniel =] my bad about that, when i rewrote the code with your locations and declarations i've ended up making that, sorry =] can you just mark the answer so this question dosen't stay on the unanswered question